# How to prove this equation of limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Sorry, I am using iPad to put forward the question so latex may be inconvenient.

Suppose we have the function as shown below

$$
F(x)_{m} =
\begin{cases}
 F(x)& \text{  when } F(x) < m \\
 m & \text{ when } F(x) \geq m
\end{cases}
$$

So when m goes to infinity, what is the limit of $F(x)_{m}$

I know the answer is F(x), but not clear about the proof

Here is my solution

For a fixed $x$, if F(x) < m, then we have $F(x)_{m} = F(x)$
, so as m goes to infinity, we still have the equation

Now if F(x)> m, then we have $F(x)_{m}= m$ , and since m goes to infinity, F(x) goes to infinity? Are they equal to each other?

Comment: I think you could also write the function as
$$
F(x)_m = \min (F(x), m)
$$

Comment: You should learn a bit of mathjax. You may visit the [mathjax tutorial especially written for beginners](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site) as well as the [more comprehensive version](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also I don't think using mathjax on iPad should be a problem. FYI I use this website exclusively on a mobile phone.

Comment: @MattiP. Yes but in this way, it may be more convenient to calculate.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ok thank you, I will learn definitely

Comment: And coming back to your question, the key thing to observe here is that the limit variable is $m$ and the $x$ can be treated just as a constant as far as $\lim_{m\to\infty} $ is concerned. Can you now try to evaluate the limit?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes I tried and when dealing with $F(x)>m$, I got a problem, as $F(x)_{m}$and$ F(x) $both go to infinity, how can I prove they are equal

Comment: Remember $x$ is constant so $F(x) $ is constant and can't go to $\infty $. And since $m\to\infty $ we can consider $m>F(x) $. The case $m<F(x) $ does not matter when evaluating the limit as $m\to\infty $.

Comment: Also it is better to put your ideas and thoughts (as seen in your comments) into the question body. Otherwise the question runs the risk of getting closed for lack of context.

Comment: Also, remember what the definition of $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = y$ is. I'm sure you can directly use that here.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I put up my thoughts, can you please check that.

Comment: Looks fine. I have given an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

To put precisely what you have thought and what Paramananda Singh suggested:

If $x$ is fixed, then there exists an integer $M$ such that $F(x) < M$. Hence for all integers $n>M$, $F(x)<n$. Hence for all $n\geq M$, $F_n(x) =F(x)$. Hence,
$$|F_n(x) -F(x)|= 0 <\epsilon,$$
for all $n\geq M$ and for any $\epsilon$ which is precisely the definition of pointwise convergence of $F_n(x)$.

And your last argument, that as $m$ goes to infinity, $F(x)$ doesn't go to infinity. Because, $F(x)$ value doesn't depend on $m$. It is fixed.